# Multiple conditions in For loop batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, line, cmd

I'd like to print each line of 2 separate txt files alternately using a for loop in a batch file, I tried using an AND but was given: "AND was unexpected at this time" in cmd.exe when I ran my batch. Any ideas?

```
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F in (!logPath!) AND for /f "tokens=*" %%H in (%%refLogPath) DO ( 

  REM print each line of log file and refLog file sequentially 
  echo %%F
  echo %%H
  REM set logLine=%%F
  REM check 'each line' of log file against ENG-REF.log

 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a keyword like `AND`, normally you couldn't solve this with two FOR loops.
But there is an alternative way to read a file with `set /p`.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<file2.txt (
  FOR /F "delims=" %%A in (file1.txt) DO (
    set /p lineFromFile2=
    echo file1=%%A, file2=!lineFromFile2!
  )
)
```

Comment: Blank lines in either file and/or differing line counts will cause problems as currently written. Also OP needs to be aware that no line can exceed 1021 bytes in the file that is being read by SET /P.

Comment: can you explain what set /p lineFromFile2= is suppose to accomplish. I see no promptString to the right of the '=' sign. @dbenham How do you suggest that this can be fixed?

Comment: The set /p line reads a line from stdin and assigns the value to a variable. Since stdin has been redirected to your file, it reads a line from the file. No prompt is required. As far as "fixing" the code, it depends on what the requirements are. Can a line exceed 1021 characters (bytes) in length? Can a line be blank in either file? If both files can exceed the 1021 char set /p length limit, and both can have blank lines, then any batch solution will be quite slow.

Comment: @jerryh91 - There are additional limitations to this solution. I've posted a more robust, albeit slower alternative. There I compare in detail the limitations of the two techniques. Some of the techniques I used in my solution can be used in this one to eliminate *some* of the limitations here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is as robust as a batch solution can get.

- It handles blank lines in both files
- It can read up to approximately 8k bytes on each line
- The number of lines in the files does not have to match
- A line can begin with any character (avoiding a FOR /F EOL issue)
- A line can contain `!` without getting corrupted (avoiding a problem of expanding a FOR 
  variable while delayed expansion is enabled)
- Lines can be either Unix or Windows style.
- Control characters will not be stripped from end of line

But this solution will get progressively slower as it reads a large file because it must rescan the 2nd file from the beginning for every line.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file1=file1.txt"
set "file2=file2.txt"
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<"%file2%"') do set file2Cnt=%%N
findstr /n "^" "%file1%" >"%file1%.tmp"
findstr /n "^" "%file2%" >"%file2%.tmp"
set "skip=0"
set "skipStr="
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%file1%.tmp") do (
  set "ln1=%%A"
  call :readFile2
  set /a "skip+=1"
)
if %file2Cnt% gtr %skip% (
  for /f "usebackq skip=%skip% delims=" %%B in ("%file2%.tmp") do (
    set "ln2=%%B"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "ln2=!ln2:*:=!"
    (echo()
    (echo(!ln2!)
  )
)
del "%file1%.tmp" 2>nul
del "%file2%.tmp" 2>nul
exit /b

:readFile2
if %skip% gtr 0 set "skipStr=skip=%skip% "
if %file2Cnt% gtr %skip% (
  for /f "usebackq %skipStr%delims=" %%B in ("%file2%.tmp") do (
    set "ln2=%%B"
    goto :break
  )
) else set "ln2="
:break
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ln1=!ln1:*:=!"
if defined ln2 set "ln2=!ln2:*:=!"
(echo(!ln1!)
(echo(!ln2!)
exit /b
```

Much better to use [jeb's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11231447/1012053) if that solution's limitations are not a concern with your files. It currently has the following limitations that could be removed with fairly minor modifications:

- Files must have same number of lines
- Files must not have blank lines
- File1 must not contain `!` character
- No line in File1 can start with `;`

In addition it has the following limitations when reading File2 that are inherent to the SET /P limitations

- Lines must be Windows style, ending in carriageReturn lineFeed
- Lines cannot exceed 1021 characters (bytes) excluding the line terminators
- Control characters will be stripped off the end of each line

An even better solution would be to use something other than batch. There are many possibilities: VBS, JScript, PowerShell, perl ... the list goes on and on.